# Displaying wpf content over/outside main window bounds

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, clipping, mainwindow

I am trying to achieve an effect of overlapping the main window boundary with a control. It's hard to explain this in words which is also maybe why I am having difficulty finding information on how to do this or if it is even possible.

Below is an example of the effect I am trying to get (from the designer), where the "note" objects float outside the bounds of the main window.

[image: Example 1]

However the effect I get at runtime is this (below), the inner controls are clipped by the boundary of the main window.

[image: Example 2]

**Can someone please tell me if this is possible (or not), and if it is maybe some suggestions about how I could get this effect.**

Comment: Have you considered using a `Popup`?

Comment: Thanks, I think the Popup control is the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to draw outside the bounds of a window. However, you could simply create a new window for the note control and align it to your main window.

Comment: The other answer seems to negate this one.

Comment: The Popup control actually creates a new window internally, as I suggested in the answer.

Comment: That is true. Maybe you could expand your answer with a short explanation on how using a popup will similarly just create a new window as well.

Answer (score 9):

There is a control that can achieve this kind a behavior have you tried a **Popup** control?
Check [this out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613596(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here's an examp;e"

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="MainButton" Content="Show popup" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MainButton}" Placement="Bottom" AllowsTransparency="True" IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=MainButton, Path=IsChecked}">
        <Grid>
            <Border BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="1" Background="Yellow"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry"/>
        </Grid>            
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

Contents of window will always get clipped. So basically there is only one way to go here. You could get the desired effect by creating a new transparent window for your floating content and then manualy set and update the position of floating content window based on the location of main window.

So far I've been using [AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/) for similar functionalty. You might give it a try...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [ClipToBounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds.aspx) property?